# Function to split string by commas, inserting into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a function which will split by commas and insert into a table with the columns 'Num' and 'String'.

The input string would look something like

With the Number being in the num column and the name being in the string column.

So far i have

```
drop function dbo.GetCommaSplit;
go

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetCommaSplit (@String varchar(max))
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN 
(
WITH Splitter (Num, String)
AS

FROM dbo.Numbers
WHERE Num <= LEN(@String)
AND (SUBSTRING(@String, Num - 1, 1) = N',' OR Num = 0)
)
SELECT
RTRIM(LTRIM(String)) AS Word
FROM Splitter
WHERE String <> ''
);
GO
```

But this splits everything and gives a new row each time, which is not what i am looking for.

\
Cheers

Comment: so you want output like 'Michael,Tito,Jermaine,Marlon' and '1,2,3,4' just one row for the string you have given ???

Comment: One row would be 1 | Michael, the next row would be 2 | tito.. etc, does that make sense?

Comment: you want 8 rows in given string ???

Comment: Given string would have 4 rows and 2 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
;with cte as
(
select 
    1 as rn, 
    CHARINDEX(',',@string, 0) pos, 
    LEFT(@string,CHARINDEX(',',@string, 0) -1) as word, 
    substring(@string,CHARINDEX(',',@string, 0) +1, LEN(@string)) as string
union all
select
    rn+1,
    CHARINDEX(',',string, 0) pos, 
    case when CHARINDEX(',',string, 0) >0 then  LEFT(string,CHARINDEX(',',string, 0) -1) else string end as word, 
    case when CHARINDEX(',',string, 0) >0 then  substring(string,CHARINDEX(',',string, 0) +1, LEN(string)) else null end as string
from cte
where CHARINDEX(',',string, 0) >=0
)
select c1.word as Num, c2.word as Name from    
(select * from cte where rn %2=0) c1
inner join
(select * from cte) c2
    on c1.rn =c2.rn+1
```

Comment: @JohnSmith You replace everything inside the `return` brackets.

Comment: Seems to be fine apart from this error "Column names in each view or function must be unique. Column name 'word' in view or function 'GetCommaSplit' is specified more than once." Do you know why this is happening?